# How to get updated html after changing page element values using puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

I'm at a loss.  I'm typing into an input element on the page using this:

```
await page.type('#username', 'test');
```

Then I'd like to retrieve the newly updated, which I'm trying using this:

```
let html = await page.content();
```

But the username field does not include the word 'test' in it - it is empty.  If I take a screenshot, it has the word 'test' in it.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing in an `<input>` element updates the `value` property but leaves the `value` attribute unchanged. This is why you don't see the text in the rendered HTML.

To get the `value` property:

```
await page.type('#username', 'test');
let value = await page.$('#username').getProperty('value');
```